# Is there a way to add both Knowledge (religion) and Knowledge (the planes) to the Spellthief skill list?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, skills, races

... Other than taking Skill Knowledge twice? (or Skill Knowledge + Apprentice)

I'd like this character to enter Ur Priest at level 6, so he needs max ranks in Knowledge (religion) and 5 in Knowledge (the planes), neither of which are class skills for Spellthief. And both feats are also going into qualifications. (Yes I know the Otyugh hole could give Iron Will or flaws could give bonus feats, but those are inelegant.)

As a human, the character would have spare feat for adding the two as class skills. Is there a feat that could pull that off?

Or, is there a race that would make them class skills by default? Or for that matter, a race that gets one of them as a class skill and one of the feats I need as a bonus feat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Education" feat makes all knowledges class skills.

It appears in the "Eberron Campaign Setting" and in "Player's Guide to Faerun".

Each setting has it's own prerequisites, so that will depend on your DM.

Comment: Thanks, using Spellthief is *so* much more elegant than my other idea for this build.

Comment: (The Education one from *PG* offers a bigger bonus, but the one from *ECS* was published afterward, making that version with its littler bonus technically more legal.)